# how to calculate volume in(liters) for a specific height in horizontal cylinder

Tags: algebra-precalculus, volume

I have horizontal cylinder with diameter = 193.04 inches and length = 548.64 inches
I want to find the volume of an oil at specific height with the help of some formula.

I came across below formula to calculate volume at specific height

$$A = \pi a^2/2 - a^2\arcsin(1-h/a) - (a-h)\sqrt{h(2a-h)}.$$

I have a dip chart available for this tank

```
Dip(cms)   Volume (in liters)
2          27.31
4          77.05  
6          147.44
8          223.36
10         309.81
12         412.40
14         515.66 
16         625.08
```

Above formula is giving me some other values. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: The formula is correct (mathematically exact), assuming `a` is the radius and `A` is the area of the cross section. The volumes in the dip chart are about ~4 times too large, but not by a constant factor so I don't understand where they come from. What exactly do you want help with? An explanation of how the formula is derived, or why the dip chart is wrong?

Comment: Why mathematical formula is not matching with dip chart volume? is there any units difference ? like cm and inches ?

Comment: You can use the formula for either kind of units, but in order to get the volume in liters I first converted the diameter and length to cm: 193.04 inches = 76.00 cm, and 548.64 inches = 216.00 cm. Using h = 2cm in the formula gave the volume 7045 cubic cm, which is 7.045 liters. The wrong dip chart values could come from mixed-up units, but I don't see any obvious pattern that explains why they differ by a factor of almost but not quite 4.

Comment: How come `193.04 inches = 76 cms`? I did not get that.

Comment: Ooops! I did the opposite unit conversion by mistake, and noticed that both numbers were integer multiples of 2.54, so I never double-checked. Of course, 193.04 inches = 490.32 cm, and 548.64 inches = 1393.55 cm. So ignore my previous comment. The dip chart values are still wrong, but ~16 times too small rather than too large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how the volume is calculated. Let $L$ be the length of the cylinder, let $a$ be the radius, and let $A$ be the area of the shaded cross-section in the picture below:

[image]

The volume $V$ will be:

$$V = L \cdot A$$

To calculate $A$ we just need to calculate the difference between the "pie section" and the triangle that is cut off by the chord:

$$A = \theta a^2 - \frac{1}{2}a \cdot 2 sin \theta \cdot a \cdot cos \theta = a^2 (\theta - sin \theta \cdot cos \theta) $$

$\theta$ can be calculated from $a \cdot cos \theta = a - h$, but in order to derive the formula in the original question, let's use the angle $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$ instead. Substituting $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$ gives:

$$A = \frac{\pi a^2}{2} - \varphi a^2 - a^2 cos \varphi \cdot sin \varphi $$

Eliminate $cos\varphi$:

$$A = \frac{\pi a^2}{2} - \varphi a^2 - a^2 sin \varphi \cdot \sqrt{1-sin^2 \varphi}$$

Since $a \cdot sin \varphi = a-h$, we have $sin\varphi = 1-\frac{h}{a}$ and $\varphi = arcsin(1-\frac{h}{a})$. So the above formula becomes:

$$A = \frac{\pi a^2}{2} - a^2 arcsin(1-\frac{h}{a}) - a^2(1-\frac{h}{a}) \sqrt{1-(1-\frac{h}{a})^2} $$

After simplification of the last term this is identical to the original formula:

$$A = \frac{\pi a^2}{2} - a^2 arcsin(1-\frac{h}{a}) - (a-h)\sqrt{h(2a-h)}$$