# Calculate segment area of circle knowing only R and h

Tags: geometry, area

I have an in-ground horizontal cylindrical water tank that I've been told holds 10,000 gallons. I have a wooden dip stick that I lower into the tank from the top and from that I can determine the current depth of water. I was also able to use that to measure the diameter of the tank.

In [this Math StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899361/how-to-calculate-volume-inliters-for-a-specific-height-in-horizontal-cylinder) the person knows both the diameter and length of the cylinder. I have different information which is the diameter, height (depth) and total volume. (I do not have the length.) How can I work out how full the tank is with this information?

I feel that the solution to this question does not initially involve volume but rather just calculating the simple area of the circle and then the area of the segment (either empty or full) and that provides the ratio/percent to multiply against the total volume. If that is correct then my current struggle is how to calculate the area of the segment give the height and diameter. Can anyone help solve this or point me in the right direction?

Update:

I've added the image from the Wikipedia article listed in the comments. My current struggle is that I only have the values of R, h and (implicitly) d. The formula in Wikipedia and Wolfram and other locations assume more information than this like the angle.

[image]

(Side note: horizontal cylindrical water tanks like this also have convex ends that we are ignoring for this exercise and we are pretending that this is shaped like a drum. That is why calculating the 2-dimensional area of the circles segment should be sufficient.)

Comment: What have you tried? Given you know both the depth and the diameter, can you not find the area of the cross section that is filled with water?

Comment: you may want to go through this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment

Comment: The volume is $V=\pi r^2 h$. Consider duplicating a circle continuously over the interval $[0, h]$ as a sort of extrusion process.

Comment: @MathLover - struggling to get my head around the formula with those inputs.

Comment: @MathLover following that link I have R and h (and obviously implicitly d). Struggling to work out how to get the other values like the angle to complete the equation.

Comment: @JPwin the cylinder is lying horizontally and not vertically. I think that the formula you are giving is for a vertically oriented cylinder. Is that correct?

Comment: You can reparametrize any basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so the formula is the same in either case. You could write $V=\pi r^2 w$ without affecting the validity of the result.

Comment: You need to go step by step. Draw a diagram. If you know $R$ and $h$, draw triangle using the chord where water level is, find angle subtended by it on the center using trigonometric function. Please edit the question with your efforts and I will help you complete the work.

Comment: @MathLover finding the angle relies on having the value for c which I don't have and cannot work out how to calculate. I added more info to the question and I removed the volume tag from this question because I feel that this is an area % question. i.e. once I know the percent of the area occupied or unoccupied I can use that to determine volume given that I know total volume. So volume is a misleading aspect of this question.